# get elements from an array in the jsf selectonemenu

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, selectonemenu

How to get print elements from an array in the JSF selectOneMenu,
i am having an array in one bean class as

```
String[] leaveTypeArray;
```

Any suggestion for this ?

Comment: You don't iterate, you use `<f:selectItems>` (note the **s** at the end of the tag component name).

Comment: can you give me a sample code

Comment: You can find many starter examples of code at the wiki (info) page of the added tag.

Comment: Also, you can search for `<f:selectItems>` in the net...

Comment: I cant understand what to put in the itemlabel and itemvalue  <f:selectItems value="#{leaveBean.leaveDTO.leaveTypeArray}" var="lType" itemValue="#{lType.leaveType}" itemLabel="#{lType.leaveType}" />

Comment: `itemLabel` evaluates to a String that will serve as the label to be shown for the item. `itemValue` is where you should stock the selected item (to be defined in the managed-bean). The essential is itemValue, it means you can omit itemLabel, and then, the itemValue will serve as itemLabel too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [luiggi-mendoza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1065197/luiggi-mendoza)  said that `<f:selectItems>` will be a good one.

You can do it with List , just add the items in List or String[] in bean class

**Bean(via List) :**

```
List listValue=new ArrayList[];

static
{
  listValue.add("First");
  listValue.add("Second");
  listValue.add("Third");
}
//Create getters and setters for listValue
```

**Bean(via array) :**

```
String[] listValue={"First", "Second", "Third"};

//Create getters and setters for listValue
```

**JSF page**

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{result value}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{bean.listValue}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Refer : [Primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf)

Comment: but cant we directly access the array itself in the selectonemenu.instead of again creating a new list and adding string objects..just to know..